# Need to compare the SQL output date with the sysdate/currentdate in batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, compare, sqlcmd

I want to compare the SQL output (which will be a single row date in the format YYYYMMDD) with the current date. If the date are same, code will exit, but if the date are not same I need to trigger an email. Please help me to get this. Till now I could get the date output on cmd console. Also the cmd prompts wait for the user input after that.

```
sqlcmd -S 10.XXX.XX.XXX -d BE_MI_DEV -U user1 -P pass$ -q "select max(day_id) from table1"
```

Above command gives me output on console as

```
   20180920

(1 rows affected)
```

Note: I will be scheduling this batch and it will run daily.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZtN2.png)

Comment: You might to take a peek [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some ideas about making this question better. As it sits right now it is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need to write a batch script, which will be scheduled daily at a particular time. Now what I want in my batch script is the logic of comparing dates. I ahve a SQL Server in a which I have a particualr table. From that table I'm getting the date, in the above mentioned format. Now I need to compare that date with the currentdate. Ideally it should match. But if not matching then trigger an email saying that the date is micmatched. In short we are just checking that the database table has the latest data. Let me know if more clarifications needed on it.

Comment: You should move your last comment to the question as the comments are horrible for formatting.

Comment: You could add a where clause to check for today's date and send the email if it returns no rows.

Comment: So I'm stuck with how will I compare both the dates. Like taking it into variable and then compare those variable or taking it into file and then compare both  the files. This are the approach I can think of, but as I dont have experience of developing/writing batch, not able to proceed further.

Comment: Simply add Where MAX(day_id) = convert(date, getdate()). If there are no rows send your email.

Comment: i think what @SeanLange mean should be something like `select 1 from table1 having max(day_id) = convert(date, getdate())`

Comment: Actually I didn't mean to leave on MAX. Simply. Where day_id = convert(date, getdate())

Comment: OK.. so with the where clause I'm completed with my logic implementation. Now the last help I need is - how will I check in batch that the SQL has returned me the result.  select max(day_id) from table1 having MAX(day_id) = convert(date, getdate());